# How to get antialiasing mode as used in text components (underlying system/OS setting)

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, antialiasing

So I'm trying to make a small text preview with line numbers by inheriting from a `JTextArea` and overwriting `paintComponent()`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PreviewPane extends JTextArea {

    public PreviewPane() {
        setText( "first row\nsecond row\nthird row" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent( Graphics graphics ) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        int emWidth = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth( "m" );
        int lineHeight = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
        int baseLine = g.getFontMetrics().getAscent();

        g.translate( 2 * emWidth, 0 );
        super.paintComponent( g );

        g.translate( -2 * emWidth, 0 );

        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect( 0, 0, 2 * emWidth - 1, getHeight() - 1 );

        g.setColor( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        g.drawLine( 2 * emWidth - 1, 0, 2 * emWidth - 1, getHeight() - 1 );

        g.setColor( Color.BLACK );

        // "guessed" value for antialiasing
        g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB );
        for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
            g.drawString( String.valueOf( i ), getMargin().left, getMargin().top + baseLine + ( i - 1 ) * lineHeight );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds( 0, 0, 640, 480 );
        frame.getContentPane().add( new PreviewPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

In the marked line, I set the antialiasing hint to `RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB`. This will lead to the exact font rendering as the text area:
[image: Rendering with <code>RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB</code>]

Omitting this line just uses the default:
[image: Rendering with default]

But this will not work on every system. Querying the `FontRenderContext` or the originally assigned rendering hints from the graphics object just return `Default antialiasing text mode`, which cannot be the mode used for rendering the text area.

So my question is: **How to obtain the actually used antialiasing mode from the text component/java system?**

*Note: I'm not trying to implement a fully fledged line numbering editor, so the "inefficiency" of this solution is irrelevant. Also, I came across this issue several times in the past years when directly rendering text in component's paint methods, so this is just an example.*

Comment: Does `getRenderingHints()` reveal anything applicable?

Comment: No, as stated in the question it returns `Text-specific antialiasing enable key=Default antialiasing text mode`.

Comment: When I set the antialiasing hint as you have, I get an entry `Text-specific antialiasing enable key=LCD HRGB antialiasing text mode`.

Comment: Yes, I get that, too, when setting the mode like in the source snippet. But what I was wondering is, why I get "default" when not setting it, although the text area renders in "LCD HRGB".

Comment: It's a hint, not a setting. A particular `Graphics2D` implementation can choose it by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging through the Java lib source reveals that font rendering of text area (and presumably the other text components as well) use internal class `sun.swing.SwingUtilities2`. This holds the desired information internally and queries it from the `java.awt.Toolkit`.

So the code to get text antialiasing information from the system is:

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Map map = (Map) tk.getDesktopProperty( sun.awt.SunToolkit.DESKTOPFONTHINTS );
g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, map.get( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING ) );
```

The content of the map is (in my case)

```
{Text-specific antialiasing enable key=LCD HRGB antialiasing text mode, Text-specific LCD contrast key=120}
```

which is the exact information needed.

Note that `sun.awt.SunToolkit.DESKTOPFONTHINTS` is forbidden API and therefore should be replaced by `"awt.font.desktophints"`.